# Is there a non-saturated measure?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal {M}, \mu) $be a measure space. A subset $E$ of $X$ is **locally measurable**, if for each $B \in \mathcal M$ with $\mu (B) < \infty$, we have $E \cap B \in \mathcal M$. The measure $\mu$ is **saturated** if every locally measurable set is measurable.

Is there a non-saturated measure such that there is  a locally measurable set isn't measurable?

All I know is that a non-saturated measure can't be a $\sigma$-finite measure.

Comment: Are you simply asking "Is every measure saturated"?

Comment: @DavidMitra: Yes. More precisely, I want to know a counterexample.

Comment: On $[0,1]$, let $\cal M$ consist of sets $A$ such that $A$ is countable or $A^c$ is countable. For $A\in\cal M$, let $\mu(A)=0$ if $A$ is countable and $\mu(A)=\infty$ if $A^c$ is countable. Consider a set $E$ with both $E$ and $E^c$ uncountable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there are measures that are not saturated.

On $X=[0,1]$, let $\cal M$ consist of the subsets $A$ of $X$ such that $A$ is countable or $A^c$ is countable. For $A\in\cal M$, define the measure $\mu$ by setting  $\mu(A)=0$ if $A$ is countable and $\mu(A)=\infty$ if $A^c$ is countable. Consider a set $E$ such that both $E$ and $E^c$ are uncountable.